# How to store a string got by getline() function into a character array?

Tags: c++11, getline, character-arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ; 
int main()
{
    string str ;
    getline(cin,str);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Now I want to store the string got by the getline() into a character array.
I was wondering what to do after this ?

Sorry if this is a very basic question. I am a beginner.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to produce a `char*` that you can pass into a function, you can just use [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) to get the `char*` out of the `std::string`.

```
const char* cstring = str.c_str();
```

If you want to copy it into an existing `char[]`, then you can use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), assuming that there are no NULL characters in your string.

```
char buffer[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), str.size());
```